# SSL on app - nginx web server

Tags: nginx, web-server, ubuntu-12.04

I am running an nginx web server where I redirect all http requests to https (with a self signed cert).

Here is how I REDIRECT all http requests to https in the nginx config file:

```
server { 
listen 80 default_server; 
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; 
server_name my.server.ip; 
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

Problem is - I cannot seem to do so for an app running on a port. Example:

**http**://my.server.ip:1234 **does not redirect** to **https**://my.server.ip:1234

ir works fine on all other urls like http://my.server.ip/temp etc.

How can I modify the nginx config file to force that app url through ssl?

Comment: I got the auto http to https working this way:'server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
server_name my.server.ip;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;'

Comment: But that does not redirect the app link http to https mentioned in op

Comment: Please edit your question and include that info in a proper code block. It's unreadable in the comment. Include what you did try to modify this to handle requests on port 1234.

Comment: done.. sorry still figuring the site out

Comment: That server block is listening only on port 80. How do you expect it to do anything with connections to port 1234?

Comment: so you're saying to add a block for port 1234 with the same contents?

Comment: You could just add some more `listen` directives to server above. But it's really weird, why do you want to do so in first place?

Comment: I want to make sure my connection to the application is encrypted. So I want it to be https

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out how to set up your application to work with https.

The app has to use a different port for http and https connections.

If the app has no support for https, then you have to pass all the traffic through nginx. The configuration would look something like this:

```
server {
    listen 1234 ssl;
    listen [::]:1234 ssl ipv6only=on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate/file;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key/file;
    error_page 497 =301 https://domain.name:1234$request_uri;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1235;
}
```

Here we an nginx server block that listens to SSL connections on port 1234. All HTTPS requests to port 1234 are proxied to the application listening on port 1235.

The `error_page 497` directive redirects all HTTP requests made to the 1234 port to https version.

You cannot assign the same port to the application and nginx, therefore I chose 1236 for the application.

Comment: Hi there, I am trying this but I get the error:

nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:116
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out - posting here for others... Basically @Tero gave me the idea to pass all the traffic through nginx. Here is how I did it:

```
server {
        listen 1234 ssl;
        listen [::]:1234 ssl ipv6only=on;
        server_name your.server.ip.here;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate/file;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key/file;
        error_page 497 =301 https://$server_name:1234$request_uri;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://$server_name:4321;
}

}
```

In the example above - my "application" is configured to run on port 4321. I will access it via the browser using port 1234 and it will "proxy pass" it to 4321 in the background via https.

Hope this helps anyone else wondering :)